# Add external script in head after CSS loading

Tags: 7, javascript

My question maybe is a little bit strange.
I have Drupal 7.x and i need to add in `<head>` a script to verify my adsense account:

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

I tried to use `drupal_add_html_head` (in `template.php)`:

```
$adsense = array(
'#type' => 'html_tag',
'#tag' => 'script',
'#attributes' => array(
    'data-ad-client' =>  'ca-pub-xxxxxxx',
    'async' => 'async',
    'src' =>  'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js')
);

drupal_add_html_head($adsense, 'adsense');
```

And works but not well because this script block Css loading, infact i should before load CSS and then add this script.
How can i solve this ?

Now some pages are without `css`

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I don't have a D7 site handy to check, but it might be as simple as setting a high `#weight` on your render array

Comment: @Clive i solve creating html.tpl.php and adding, inside, in head the code.